# エラーメッセージ：No Ransack::Search object was provided to search_form_for!の解決方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**前提・実現したいこと**

Ruby on railsにてイベント一覧が表示されるシステムを作っています。 
そのイベントを検索する機能を実装するべく、gemの「Ransack」を導入しようとしておりますが、その際に下記のエラーメッセージが表示されてしまい困っております。 
是非ともアドバイス頂きたくお願い申し上げます。

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**

```
    ArgumentError in Home#top
No Ransack::Search object was provided to search_form_for!


Extracted source (around line #3):
              <% if user_signed_in? %>
  <aside class="sidebar">
  <%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name_cont, 'イベント名' %>
```

なお、こちらも合わせてご確認下さい。
https://gyazo.com/c9374b17b436d0b09524d91e09bb8d5a

**以下コード記載致します。**

**top.html.erb**

```
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
  <aside class="sidebar">
  <%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name_cont, 'イベント名' %>
    <%= f.text_field :name_cont, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class ="form-group">
    <%= f.label :start_time_qteq, '開催日' %>
    <div>
      <%= f.date_select :start_time_qteq, prompt:true %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit '検索', class: 'byn btn-default' %>
  <% end %>

  </aside>

    <ul class="notes">
    <h2>イベントの一覧</h2>
   <%= render @events %>
   <%= paginate @events %> 
  </ul>


<% else %>
  <div class="top-wrapper">
    <%= image_tag "gatebook_cover.png" %>
    <div class="register-wrapper">
      <h1><%= @message %></h1>
      <%= link_to "新規登録", new_user_registration_path, class: "btn btn-large register-btn" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**home_controller.rb**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

PER = 3

def top
    if user_signed_in?
      @note = Note.new
      @notes = Note.all.order(created_at: :desc)
      #@event = Event.new
      #@events = Event.all.order(created_at: :desc)
      @event = Event.new
      @events = Event.all.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per(PER)
      @user = User.new
      #@q = Event.ransack(params[:q])
      #@events = @q.result(distinct: true)
    else
      @message = "ようこそプロトタイプサイトへ！"
    end
  end

def index
@q = Event.search(params[:q])
@events = @q.result(distinct: true)
end

private

def search_params
  params.require(:q).permit!
  resocue
  { start_time_qteq: Time.zone.now }
  end

  def about
  end

  include ApplicationHelper
end
```

**events_controller.rb**

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  include ApplicationHelper

  def show
  end

  def index
    @events = Event.all
  end

  def new
   event = Event.new
  end

  def create
    @event = current_user.events.build(event_params)
    if @event.save
      redirect_to @event, notice: "投稿が保存されました"
    else
      # @notesを定義してください
      @events = Event.all.order(created_at: :desc)
      # renderメソッドで表示するビューが、views/home/top.html.erbになるように変更してください
      render 'home/top'

    end
  end

  def edit
  end

 def update
    file = params[:event][:image]
    @event.set_eventimage(file)

    if @event.update(event_params)
      redirect_to @event, notice: 'ユーザー情報が更新されました'
    else
      render :edit
    end
 end
```

**event.rb**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :place, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 2000 }
  validate :start_time
  validate :end_time
  validate :start_time_should_be_before_end_time

  belongs_to :user

  paginates_per 2

  private

  def start_time_should_be_before_end_time
    return unless start_time && end_time

    if start_time >= end_time
      errors.add('開始時間は終了時間よりも前に設定してください')
    end
  end

  def set_eventimage(file)
      if !file.nil?
        file_name = file.original_filename
        File.open("public/event_images/#{file_name}", 'wb'){|f| f.write(file.read)}
        self.image = file_name
      end
  end


end
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
 # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
   gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
 # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
   gem 'sqlite3'
 # Use SCSS for stylesheets
   gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
 # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
   gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
 # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
   gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
  # See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
 # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
 # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
   gem 'jquery-rails'
  # Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
 # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more:        https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
 gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
 # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
 gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
 # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
 # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
 # Use Unicorn as the app server
 # gem 'unicorn'
  # Use Capistrano for deployment
  # gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
    group :development, :test do
   # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
   gem 'byebug'
   end
   group :development do
   # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'hirb'
gem 'devise', '3.5.1'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.0'
gem 'ransack', '~> 1.2.2'
end
```

**その他必要な情報があれば、ご教示頂きたくお願い申し上げます。**
何卒よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

`Ransack`を使っていないので自信はないのですが、

`home/top`でエラーが発生してるので Controller内でも `top`で`@q`に値を入れておく必要があるのではないでしょうか。

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def top
    @q = Event.search(params[:q])
    @events = @q.result(distinct: true)
    #...

  end
end
```

でどうでしょうか。